# Stopping UDP packets from being partially chopped off when receive buffer is almost full

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, buffering

I'm working on implementing the sliding window protocols in C++ for an assignment. I am using UDP (SOCK_DGRAM) sockets. Occasionally, the program must send a large number of packets (as large as the window size) back to back. So far, I have not increased the window size past 30, but it should be able to reach 256 eventually. The packet size must be taken from user input, so it could be anything reasonable. When the packet size is small, like 512 bytes, there aren't problems. When the packet size is larger, as in 40KB, the first few packets are read correctly, and then suddenly my readNBytes() function hangs on one of them after reading only part of it. I'm assuming that the operating system's receive buffer is being filled, and that part of one of the packets is being thrown away. The part that makes it into the buffer is read, and then readNBytes() is waiting for the rest, which was discarded by the OS.

When this happens, are there any flags set by the OS for me to read? Ideally, I would like to force the OS to throw away the entire packet if it does not fit into the receive buffer, instead of just taking part of it. IP_DONTFRAG is not defined on my system, so I don't know how to do this. I would also settle for a way to make the receive buffer size a multiple of my packet size, so that a packet couldn't partially fit into the buffer. What is the best way to overcome this issue?

Comment: IP packets usually have a maximum size of about 1500 bytes.  With jumbo frames that can go up to 9K or 10K.    So a packet size of 512 bytes is not small, and a packet size of 40K is unheard of - at least for now.

Comment: @CraigS.Anderson I thought the maximum IP packet size was ~65K

Comment: IP packets have a absolute size limit of 64K.  In practice, the limit is 1.5K without jumbo frames or about 9K with jumbo frames.  Remember that IP packets need to fit inside an Ethernet, 802.11x, token ring, etc. frame.

Comment: The OS is not going to pass half a packet to the application. It is IP's responsibility to handle fragmentation on the send side, IP packets can go up to 64K, and will be fragmented by IP to fit into the underlying layer's MTU. On the receive side the opposite happens, reassembly. With UDP you either receive the whole packet, or nothing. The only reason to receive only a part of it might be that your application receive buffer is small. Some socket implementations chop it of, even though everything was received.

Comment: Conclusion: show your code.

Comment: @CraigS.Anderson your explanation is totally confusing. The reality is that 1 IP packet is fragmented over different ethernet frames. All these frames belong to the same IP packet. The bottom line is that an application using a UDP socket does not have to care about the mtu and can send up to 64k.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck - since hosts can drop fragmented packets greater than 576 (v4) or 1500 (v6) bytes, sending a 64k packet is not the best idea.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck The OS is indeed going to pass half a *datagram* to the application if the `recv()` buffer is only half the size of the datagram.

Comment: @CraigS.Anderson I never said it was a good idea. But it is good to mention that it is best to take the mtu into account even at the application level, which is what you meant probably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OS is not going to pass half a packet to the application.

It is IP's responsibility to handle fragmentation on the send side, IP packets can go up to 64K, and will be fragmented by IP to fit into the underlying layer's MTU.

On the receive side the opposite happens, reassembly. With UDP you either receive the whole packet, or nothing. **The only reason to receive only a part of it might be that your application receive buffer is small. Some socket implementations chop it of, even though everything was received**

Comment: The issue was in my readNBytes and writeNBytes functions. I had been using them for months with connection-based sockets, and had forgotten that they broke up chunks of data and reassembled them on the other side. Each piece was sent separately as a datagram, and some were lost when the buffer filled. This answer helped me to find this error, by showing me what I didn't need to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

If your `recv()` buffer is too small for the datagram, it will be truncated. It does not cause blocking.

Your datagrams are far too big. The IPv4 limit is 65507 bytes but the generally accepted practical limit is 534 bytes. You should certainly aim to keep them under the path MTU, otherwise you are guaranteeing fragmentation, which only increases the chances of datagram loss.